# logrotate status files extremely large

Tags: logging, ubuntu-16.04, logrotate, du, log-rotation

Apache2 on an Ubuntu 16.04 box was showing issues on the websites it's hosting. It was at 100% capacity. Looking further with `du`, The majority of the ~100gb hard drive was filled by two files in `/var/lib/logrotate/`.

`logrotate` has files in there which are called `/var/lib/logrotate/status` and `/var/lib/logrotate/status.clean` and taking up a lot of space... 30gb and 60gb.

I'm aware that `logrotate` is used to regularly clear log files but it seems that it doesn't clear it's own 'log' files by default. I resolved the disk space issue by deleting the two files in there `rm -rf /var/lib/logrotate/*`.

(`/var/lib/logrotate/status` has repopulated with new logs from rotate processes throughout the day)

Is this something that is going to keep happening if logrotate doesn't rotate it's own logs?

Comment: The logrotate status file is not a log file. It stores the time when a file has last been rotated. If you remove or truncate the file, logrotate will consider every file as new, and therefore not rotate it, i.e. logrotate will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting or rotating the `logrotate.status` file is only a band-aid.  You need to take a step backward and ask the question, "why is the `logrotate.status` file that large?"

I would `tail -n 500` that status file and see what files are listed in there.  I think there's a real strong possibility that your logrotate config file(s) are rotating stuff you never intended to be rotated.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a cron job to either clean up or rotate/truncate the logrotate.status file on a routine basis.  I'd recommend a weekly one if your server volume is moderate, daily if extremely heavy traffic.

**To setup a weekly cron job that resets the logrotate.status file:**

1. open cron `crontab -e`
2. add the entry  `* * * * 1 echo > /var/lib/logrotate.status`

**To setup rotation of the file every week:**
Create a script (make sure it's executable by the cron user) and run a weekly cron to call the it.

Example Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mv /var/lib/logrotate.status.3 /var/lib/logrotate.status.4
/bin/mv /var/lib/logrotate.status.2 /var/lib/logrotate.status.3
/bin/mv /var/lib/logrotate.status.1 /var/lib/logrotate.status.2
/bin/mv /var/lib/logrotate.status /var/lib/logrotate.status.1
```

To set the script's file permissions:

```
chmod u+x [script-filename]
```

Cron task format:

```
* * * * 1 /full/path/to/your/script
```

Comment: This line will cause issues with all logrotate processes... `echo > /var/lib/logrotate.status`. This answer is very similar with what is found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25334099/How-to-clean-var-lib-logrotate-status.html) however it is not a solution. (The echo command will leave a blank line in the file thus corrupting the file and stopping logs from rotating)

Comment: This does not seem to be a solution. One should look into why the files are so huge, possibly there are wrong patterns in the configuration.

Comment: Not that I would recommend to do this, but if you just want to avoid the insert of a line break, you could use `echo -n /var/lib/logrotate.status`. If you want it to use a different INode, you might want to `rm /var/lib/logrotate.status && touch /var/lib/logrotate.status`. This will delete the old file and create a new (empty) one

Comment: The logrotate status file is not a log file. It stores the time when a file has last been rotated. If you remove or truncate the file, logrotate will consider every file as new, and therefore not rotate it, i.e. logrotate will stop working.